# Yield and contentFor in meteor-jade with iron-router

Tags: node.js, meteor, pug, iron-router

I want to use `{{>yield "aside"}}` with `{{#contentFor "aside"}}{{/contentFor}}` in jade with meteor and iron-router, but I got this error :

`Jade syntax error: unexpected token "indent" <runJavaScript-59>:73:14: Cannot read property 'head' of undefined (at fileModeHandler)`

What's wrong with it ?
What is the correct syntaxe in jade for spacebar equivalent to these tags ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
+contentFor("aside")
    p Hello World
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

So in your router, if your doing something like this:

```
Router.route('/some-route', function () {

  this.render('SomeRouteTemplate' {
    data: function () { return 'some data' }
  });

  this.render('MyTemplate', {
    to: 'aside',
    data: function () { return 'some data' }
  });

});
```

This should render your MyTemplate in the aside region of your Layout template and pass whatever data is needed to the template:

```
template(name="layout")

  +yield(region="aside")
```

Comment: Hmm the bug is not on this file, it appears on this tag :

`{{#contentFor "aside"}}
My Text
{{/contentFor}}`

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean. Could you describe in more detail what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok, so, I've an ApplicationLayout, with this tag:

`{{>yield "aside"}}`

and I wan't to populate it from MyTemplate (the template loaded by my RouteController, and which "inherits" from ApplicationLayout) by using this tag :

`{{#contentFor "aside"}} My Text {{/contentFor}}`

Comment: Ok I've updated my answer. Hopefully this can clear up some things for you.